# Is there a DBGrid component that can handle large datasets fast?

Tags: performance, delphi, dataset, dbgrid

Large datasets, millions of records, need special programming to maintain speed in DBGrids.

I want to know if there are any ready-made components for Delphi (DBGrids) that do this automatically?

EDIT For Example: Some databases have features such as fetch 1st X records (eg 100 records). When I reach the bottom with scrolling, I want to auto fetch the next 100. Conversely when I reach the beginning, I want to fetch the previous 100. I know I can program this, but it sure is possible to propagate that feature to a DBGrid control where the DBGrid does the buffering. It will save quite a bit of programming - you simply have to set the "buffer size" so to speak.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would have a look at [Developer Express QuantumGrid Suite](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/VCL/ExQuantumGrid/key_datacontroller.xml). (@birger: you just were a tick faster ;-) ) So I'm not just duplicating the answer, some elaboration:

The DevExpress Grid uses a data controller that has several modes to controll the data bound to the grid. One of these is exactly what you are looking for:

> **Grid Mode**
>
> When using Grid Mode, only a fixed
>   number of dataset records is loaded
>   into memory. Because only a limited
>   set of records are retrieved from the
>   dataset, automatic sorting, filtering
>   and summary calculations are disabled
>   in Grid Mode (must be controlled
>   manually instead). By default, this
>   mode is disabled and the
>   ExpressDataController loads all
>   records in a dataset.

It does have some drawbacks, which seem pretty obvious: you cannot make a summary, sort, or filter if you do not have all records at hand.

Comment: Thanks for this info, hard to come by via Google. :)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the shortcomings of the DevExpress product (inability to filter, sort and summarize), especially as it is far more expensive than the alternatives mentioned here. And this drawback isn't obvious at all - the whole point of these virtual datasets is that the heavy lifting is done server-side; the control only manipulates the SQL to pull just the data it needs over the network.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to take a look at the wonderful (free, open source, dual licensed as MPL 1.1 and GPL thus usable in closed source apps) [Virtual TreeView](http://www.soft-gems.net/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=12&Itemid=33) and its user-supplied descendants (scroll down the page to find those.)

Edit to reflect the question's edit: Virtual TreeView not only allows you to handle millions of nodes without keeping them in memory, but that is in fact the preferred way of using it. You supply the data through event callbacks when it's needed, and you can tell the tree to cache that data (or not.)

Oh, and of course it also has a grid / report mode where it can function as a table (just set the GridExtensions property to True.)

Answer (score 3):

NextGrid is light, fast and nice looking grid for Delphi

http://www.bergsoft.net/component/next-grid/features.htm

> **HANDLING LARGE AMOUNT OF CELLS WITHOUT LOOSING SPEED**
>
> NextGrid can handle very large amount
>   of cells without losing speed. Speed
>   of adding, modifying and deleting data
>   doesn't depend of the amount of cells.
>   In NextGrid demo you can see how fast
>   NextGrid work with 100,000 rows and 10
>   columns = 1,000,000 cells

Answer (score 2):

I think the [DevExpress Quantumgrid](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/VCL/ExQuantumGrid/) supports this very good.

Answer (score 1):

sorry, I just saw your comment to Neftalí

if you would to bring 100 record per time, and then fetch the next 100, this work related to database access components, look at **devart** components, they are offer direct access components to most used database, and they have the feature you are asking about and more:

http://www.devart.com/products-vcl.html

Comment: I want the DBGRid to do the buffering